# WordPress URL Rewrite Rules

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this URL:

```
example.com/products-and-services/?catID=5
```

I want to make it like this:

```
example.com/products-and-services/5
```

Basically I am removing `?catID=`

Here is my code with `add_rewrite_rule` which I have no luck so far:

```
function custom_rewrite_products() {
    add_rewrite_rule('products-and-services/([^/]+)/?$', 
    'index.php?pagename=products-and-services&catID=$matches[1]', 'top');
}

add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_products')
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
function custom_rewrite_products() {
    add_rewrite_rule(
        '^products-and-services/([^/]*)/?$',
        'index.php?pagename=products-and-services&catID=$matches[1]',
        'top'
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'custom_rewrite_products' );
```

More details here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/250837/understanding-add-rewrite-rule

Comment: @ShahGhafoori does the following URL work = example.com/products-and-services/5/ ? Please be sure to include the trailing slash.

Answer (score 0):

Use This.

```
function custom_rewrite_tags() {
    add_rewrite_tag('%catID%', '([^&]+)');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_tags', 10, 0);

function custom_rewrite_products() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^products-and-services/([\w+]*)/', 'index.php/?pagename=products-and-services&catID=$matches[1]', 'top');
}

add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_products');
```